# Is there a way to install PyQt5 to use with Pyinstaller without completely breaking Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, pyqt5, pyinstaller

Anaconda does not come with PyQt5 instead it comes with a version of it called pyqt. If you try to use this with Pyinstaller, Pyinstaller will throw essentially a can't verify version error. The way to get around this is to pip install PyQt5. However PyQt5, especially newer versions cause Anaconda and Spyder to completely break. Currently, I can't open Anaconda Navigator or Spyder even after uninstalling PyQt5, updating the navigator, re-installing the navigator, reinstalling pyqt. I think I'm going to have to do a full re-install just because I pip installed PyQt5.

Is there a way to get PyQt5, Pyinstalled and Anaconda to work together without breaking each other?

Answer (score 0):

In you **Anaconda Navigator** you can create a new conda environment. A conda environment is a seperate space with its own libraries. The PyQT anaconda comes with is always in the **base** conda environment.

Once you create a new conda environment such as:

```
conda env create -n myenv python==3.8
```

Then you can do

```
conda deactivate base
conda activate myenv
pip install pyinstaller pyqt5
```

This should set you up with everything you need in myenv. If however you want to do everything in your **base** conda environment in Anaconda (not suggested) then first do pip uninstall pyqt or conda uninstall pyqt  and then reinstall pyqt5. You can also do

```
  python -m pip install –upgrade pyqt
```